# Phonegap Application doesn't show up for Tablet in google Play Store

Tags: android, cordova, tablet, google-play

I would like to publish an App for both, Smartphone's and Tablet's with Phonegap, but my testing-app isn't showing up for Tablets in the Play Store. It's only showing up for Smartphones, altough there are Tablet devices displayed in the device compatibility list with a green Checkmark next to it.

Info:

- App is almost empty
- No Permissions are set
- support-screens has the attributes "largeScreens" and "xlargeScreens" set to true

Manifest File:

```
    <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="7" android:versionName="1.0.6" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="my.testing.app12345" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <application android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ResolutionTester" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my app is properly findable in the play store, even for tablets. The message for improving my app by creating a 7" layout for tablet users is still there, but it's installable for tablets trough the play store without problems. Strange...